# whats wrong with all jquery functions

Tags: jquery

can anyone tell me why this code is not running as expected

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

   $('#search_box').on('paste keyup change', 'input', function () {

    alert("hi");
    }
    });
 });
```

the code is working in another page, when i copied it its not working .
I know it has to be simple but I dont get it.

Comment: Did you check the script-console for errors?

Comment: did you include jquery on your page?

Comment: I voted for "Too localized". This random typo should've been dealt with by checking the error-console, and this question can hardly be useful to other users on SO.

Comment: Do you actually have a text input with the ID search_box? There are so many reasons this wouldn't work that we're all guessing here without seeing the HTML code that accompanies the jQuery

Comment: yes I have a test input with the same id, and I already included jquery on my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will let you control "paste" event over search_box control...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search_box').bind('paste', function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work either

Comment: I've tested it; it works 100%. You can paste your code into jsFiddle and let us see it ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code with problem in comment:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

   $('#search_box').on('paste keyup change', 'input', function () {

    alert("hi");
    }
    }); // the problem may be here, an extra } not needed
 });
```

Simply remove the extra `}`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#search_box').on('paste keyup change', 'input', function () {

          alert("hi");
      }
  );
});
```

Comment: well that was a typing mistake, the code doesnt have this error already.thanks

Comment: alrighty, post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and we can figure it out!